# Pass in element to function in Angular

Tags: angular

I would like to conditionally apply a title attribute to an element, which I am attempting like so:

```
<div class="option-title" [attr.title]="isTitleTruncated() ? option.title : null">
  {{option.title}}
</div>
```

But I would like to pass in the element reference to my function being used on the condition, but have been unable to do so. I tried using `this` and that gives me the component instance, but I want the actual `div` itself. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using template reference variable like:

```
<div ... #divRef [attr.title]="isTitleTruncated(divRef) ? option.title : null">
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, although I have hit a change detection error now, which I will post a separate question on

Answer (score 1):

You should create a template reference variable on the elmenent that looks like `#myDiv` and then pass it to the function.

```html
<div class="option-title" #myDiv [attr.title]="isTitleTruncated(myDiv) ? option.title : null">
  {{option.title}}
</div>
```

Comment: what is myDiv type? it just outputs markup in console.log, if i put `any` type to check it out, so it's not clear what type of data is that. I need to swap CSS class for clicked element.